# AVD starting fine, but not running my app

Tags: android, eclipse

I've been trying to learn android app development from: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html. I'm using Eclipse for that. I've downloaded and installed everything as instructed in the tutorial, and now when I'm trying to run the basic app which is described [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html), using the AVD (Android Virtual Device), it's not working. The AVD starts, I see the android home screen, but that's it, nothing else happens.
These are the settings that I've assigned to the AVD:

Device: Nexus 4 |
Target: Android 4.4W - API Level 20 |
CPU/ABI: Android Wear Intel Atom (x86) |
Hardware keyboard: check |
skin: no skin |
front/back camera: none |
Memory: Ram: 1907
        VM heap: 64 |
Internal storage: 200 |
SD Card:  |
Snapshot: unchecked |
Use host GPU: unchecked |

> I've tried re creating another avd, it didn't work

Comment: did you tried changing the API level to 19 instead of 20 ?

Comment: AVD devices might take some time to load on some machines, up to 30-40 minutes. Are you sure it's not working?

Comment: Sometimes it installs the application, but doesn't run it - so once it's installed on the AVD (check the IDE's output tab), open the AVD's menu and look for your app.

Comment: Navigate to the apps page and see if your application has been deployed.  When you deploy it you will see if its successful from the LogCat output, look carefully for any error messages!!

Comment: Okay so it started working. In the beginning I think it was just taking too much time to start, and when it started, as Montycarlo and Christian suggested, I navigated to the apps menu, and it was there! Thanks people!